# How do I change the color of options in search/replace?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

I know that there is this setting in `workbench.colorCustomizations` to change the color the options like "Regex" or "Match case":

```
"inputOption.activeBackground": "#cc1212", // eg regex icon in search field
```

But I can't find a setting to change the color of the options on the right side like "Find in selection" or "replace all". I would like them to be red when I select them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"icon.foreground": "#f00", // find and search icons, not the options
```

You can only change the foreground and not the background it seems.  And for some reason it has no effect on the `Find in Selection` button which seems like an option but isn't grouped with them so....

For the input options, like regex, wholeWord options etc. there are these commands

```
    "inputOption.activeBorder": "#666",
    "inputOption.activeBackground": "#666",
    "inputOption.activeForeground": "#fff",
```

but     `"icon.foreground"` does nothing does nothing to the options.